# In VPython when I rotate I always go around 0,0,0 how can I change this?

Tags: rotation, vpython

In VPython when I rotate the view I always rotate around the origin (0,0,0) but I am doing something where I need to be able to change it to another point. Is there a way to change the point and if so what is that way?

Comment: I'm using it for graphs -

Comment: 'def linegraph2d(lst):'

Comment: You know what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This site is pretty detailed about the view in VPython. You'll want to change the `center` position since that is where the camera looks.

http://www.vpython.org/contents/docs/visual/display.html